# File Layout Exception

Tags: java

I'm writing a java Application that can open and edit files. But I want it to give me an error if the layout of the file isnt as it should be.
My file looks like this:

```
Title
X Y
Name
X times line
```

If looked into try and catch but that doesnt give me the right solution to give an error like:

```
"There is no X or Y specified"
```

or

```
"There is nog Title in this file"
```

Whats the option to do this?

Comment: Inside the if loop, have the working code. The else loop would contain your errors, with nested if loops to catch what type of error, as we'll as a nested else loop contaning a generic error message

Answer (score 1):

Create your own `Exception` class that `extends Exception`. This is sometimes called a *domain exception*, because it's one that only applies to your problem domain.

Here's an example of how you would code it:

```
public class FileLayoutException extends Exception {
    // extending Exception means you can throw it and declare it to be thrown
}
```

Declare your method to throw it:

```
public void readFile() throws FileLayoutException {
    // some impl  
}
```

Then use it like this when you detect a problem:

```
throw new FileLayoutException("There is no X or Y specified");
```

or

```
throw new FileLayoutException("There is no Title in this file");
```

Because your error conditions are "file-related", you may consider extending `IOException` instead of `Exception`